# Vim readfile() not working

Tags: vim, macvim

It seems that I can't use `readfile()` in vim to open anything.

For instance running

```
let m = readfile('~/.vimrc')
```

Will throw an error.

```
E484: Can't open file ~/.vimrc
```

Is there any configuration that might obstruct readfile from working?

Here is my `.vimrc`, I am using (Mac)Vim 7.4

http://pastebin.com/nBnJN5bv

Comment: what does not work? `readfile` not open files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't expand shell patterns in strings by default; you need to use the [`glob()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#glob()) function:

```
let m = readfile(glob('~/.vimrc'))
```

Or just use the full path:

```
let m = readfile('/home/martin/.vimrc')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an another way:

```
let m = readfile(expand('~/.vimrc'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `vim` knows nothing about `~/` you should pass full path.

```
let m = readfile('/Absolute/path/to/file/file.ex')
```